# Need email validation without required

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I have used following code for email validation. It is running fine but i don't want to validate it when field will be empty.

```
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    var sEmail = $(this).val();

    if (!filter.test(sEmail)) {
        value = false;
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        $(this).attr('error','true');
    }else{
        $(this).css('border', '');
        $(this).removeAttr('error');
    }
```

Comment: `if ($(this).val()) => validate`.

Comment: trim `$(this).val()` and check its not empty prior to validating then?

Comment: @MLeFevre Just by testing the boolean against `.val()` will give you the result. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/jumkynzd/

Comment: @MLeFevre Yes, I just got caught on this as mentioned in the answer given by T.J. Crowder.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Yep no worries, I replied to you before I saw below :)

Comment: @MLeFevre That's OK. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments:

```
var sEmail = $.trim($(this).val());
//           ^^^^^^^-------------^---- Trim whitespace

if (sEmail && !filter.test(sEmail))
//  ^^^^^^^^^^--- only validate if there's something in it
```

Comment: I don't think you need to trim the value to check whether it's empty or not. `.val()` when tested as boolean will return false if it's empty. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/jumkynzd/

Comment: @MelanciaUK: If it's really empty, yes. But if the user types in `" "`, no.

Comment: I see your point. :)

Comment: Thanks T.J. It is working fine.